# Passing in data using graphql fragment

Tags: reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to pass the data from a component to another. I hoped my code work because the logic made sense to me, but it didn't :(

Here's my code:

From the parent file that is in the components folder, I wrote a graphql fragment:

```
export const testQuery = graphql`
  fragment testQuery on RootQueryType {
    allThePics {
      edges {
        node {
          testPicture {
            responsiveResolution {
              src
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

and then from a different js file, I called like this:

```
export const callingTestQuery = graphql`
  query callingTestQuery {
    ...testQuery
  }
`;
```

I checked this graphql using localhost:0000/___graphql, and it seems like it is giving me some data, which means data is defined.

However, when I try to use the data,

```
const Image = ({ data }) => {
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div>
      {data.allThePics.edges.map(edge => {
        <PictureList node={edge.node} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

it keeps on giving me an error, saying the data is undefined:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'allThePics' of undefined

I'm not sure how to make it work... Help :)

Comment: Well, let's see the error as text in the body of the question.

Comment: Updated! Thanks :)

Comment: were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing `data && data.allThePics...`?
If that work, it is because, during loading, data doesn't exist yet.

Another way you could try is `if(loading) return null`

more example of loading can be found here.
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/angular/basics/queries.html#basics